# How to change hotchocolate default json serializer

Tags: hotchocolate

How can i change the json serializer used by hotchocalate i could not find anything in the documentation.

i tried to look at the source code but  it seems like it hard coded in the HttpResponseExtensions .

its uses camel case so it will a pain to change all my models in the front side of the app ,
any ideas ?  i think that the team is aware of this : https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/4072 but i'm looking for a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this question when looking for a way of matching cases to Models. In my case I wanted to keep casings the same for the query input and response fields.

Got around this by adding a naming convention to override the DefaultNamingConventions:

```
public class NoCaseNamingConvention : DefaultNamingConventions
{
    public override NameString GetMemberName(MemberInfo member, MemberKind kind) {
        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(member));

        if ((kind == MemberKind.InputObjectField || kind == MemberKind.ObjectField) && member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            return member.Name;

        return base.GetMemberName(member, kind);
    }
}
```

And adding the Convention to the GraphQL:

```
services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddConvention<INamingConventions, NoCaseNamingConvention>()
    .RegisterDbContext<ApplicationContext>(DbContextKind.Pooled)
    .AddQueryType<Query>()
    .AddProjections()
    .AddFiltering()
    .AddSorting();
```

Also worth noting you can change the name of the top level response object in data:

```
public class Query
{
    [GraphQLName("Components")]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IQueryable<ComponentTable> GetComponents(ApplicationContext context) => context.Components;
}
```

[Playground Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFiM5.png)

[Playground After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVOGC.png)

Hope this is helpful to folks :)

Answer (score 0):

Schema has convention of camescase field naming. It would be wierd you return PascalCasing in response, and asking in camel case. Make deserialization in client case insensitive, and don't touch client models.